# How can I remove "openright" behaviour for a part of a latex document (appendix) so that section can also be on even pages?

Tags: document-classes, appendix, blank-page

I want to remove the blank pages when a section of my appendix starts. I use for every material in my appendix a new \section. If it is on an even page, it leaves one free/blank and starts on the next one. I suspect that this behaviour is from "openright":

```
\documentclass[english,format=a5-monografie,schriftgroesse=10,twoside,openright]{sr-vorl/sr-vorl}
```

How can I suppress this behaviour (blank pages) in my appendix while still allowing it in the chapters before?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You should probably tell us which class it is. Additionally, `\section` normally does not start a new page, so you probably need to provide a lot more information for your question

Comment: try `\let\cleardoublepage\clearpage` just after the `\appendix` command (or after the first section of it)

Comment: \makeatletter \@openrightfalse \makeatother before the appendix could work.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I tried this before and it does not work :-(

Comment: @koleygr I tried this already it is also does not work. But I do not use the \appendix tag. With inserting both, it also does not work.

Comment: @daleif what do you mean with class? {sr-vorl/sr-vorl} or \documentclass[a4paper]{ltxdoc}. Any ideas?

Comment: It will be a lot easier to help if you provide an example we can compile.  Saying your suggestion "does not work" only leaves the possibility that there's a bug in `sr-vorl`.